# Modx and Memcache setting

Tags: memcached, modx, modx-revolution

I have run a memcache server in aws. Installed memcache extension in
modx server.

Then I update the settings in modx.

cache_handler -> cache.xPDOMemCache
add a new key "resource_memcached_server" and value = xxx.com:11211

But I tail the log, there are some errors

```
[2015-01-23 14:17:13] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not cache source data
for 1.
[2015-01-23 14:17:13] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not cache source data
for 8.
[2015-01-23 14:17:13] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not cache source data
for 1.
[2015-01-23 14:17:13] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not cache source data
for 8.
[2015-01-23 14:17:13] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not cache source data
for 1.
[2015-01-23 14:17:13] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not cache source data
for 8.
[2015-01-23 14:17:13] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not cache source data
for 1.
[2015-01-23 14:17:13] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not cache source data
for 8.
[2015-01-23 14:17:13] (ERROR @ /index.php) Error caching lexicon topic
lexicon/en/wayfinder/properties
[2015-01-23 14:17:13] (ERROR @ /index.php) Error caching lexicon topic
lexicon/en/wayfinder/properties
[2015-01-23 14:17:13] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not cache context
settings for web.
[2015-01-23 14:17:14] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not cache context
settings for web.
[2015-01-23 14:17:16] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not cache context
settings for web.
[2015-01-23 14:17:16] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not cache context
settings for web.
[2015-01-23 14:17:16] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not cache context
settings for web.
[2015-01-23 14:17:17] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not cache context
settings for web.
[2015-01-23 14:17:18] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not cache context
settings for web.
```

May I know how can I fix it?

P.s Modx version MODX Revolution 2.2.14-pl (traditional)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a memcached server running?
You need to provide the IP:PORT number for MODx.

As a very basic:

- Ensure the memcache module for php is installed and working, php_info will check this
- Set the cache_handler = cache.xPDOMemCache
- Set memcached_server = myip:port
- In you are going to use memcache for your system settings, you need to add these you your config.inc.php

  $config_options = array (
      'memcached_server'                 => 'server:port',
      'system_settings_memcached_server' => 'server:port'
  );

Answer (score 0):

here is a link where all is explained
http://modx.com/blog/2012/09/24/using-memcached-for-modx-caching/